# How can I show that $n_p(A )\cdot n_p(B) = n_p(A \times B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $A,B$ be finite groups, such that a prime $p$ divides $|A|$ and $|B|$. Show that $$n_p(A )\cdot n_p(B) = n_p(A \times B).$$

Any ideas on how to proceed? I was thinking that the idea was something along the lines of $n_p(A) = n_p(A \times \{e\})$, and using that fact, but clearly no prime divides the order of $\{e\}$, so that's not helpful.

Comment: Where $n_p(A)$ is the number of $p$-Sylows of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ is a Sylow subgroup of $A$ and $Q$ is a Sylow subgroup of $B$, then $P \times Q$ is a Sylow subgroup of $A \times B$. We will show that every Sylow subgroup of $A \times B$ is of this form, which proves the claim.

Suppose that $H$ is a Sylow subgroup of $A \times B$. Let $\pi_A: A \times B \rightarrow A$ and $\pi_B: A \times B \rightarrow B$ be the projection homomorphisms. Since $\pi_A(H)$ and $\pi_B(H)$ are both $p$-groups and $H$ is contained in the product $\pi_A(H) \times \pi_B(H)$, we get $H = \pi_A(H) \times \pi_B(H)$. From this it follows that $\pi_A(H)$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $A$, because otherwise the order of $H$ would be smaller than the largest power of $p$ dividing $|A \times B|$. By the same argument $\pi_B(H)$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $Q$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$.

Is $P\times Q$ a Sylow subgroup of $G\times H$?

Comment: Thus $n_p(A)n_p(B) \leq n_p(A \times B)$, but this is not enough for equality.

Comment: @m.k. Yeah, I'm just giving OP a hint on how to proceed.  He still must make a bijection.